# Is it correct to say "Me and my friend, we..."?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, appositives

I know normally to use:

> "My friend and I went shopping."

But what about when we make it into:

> "My friend and I, we went shopping."

It seems to me that in this structure, we could or should change it to:

> "Me and my friend, we went shopping."

My reasoning is that it "sounds correct" to say "Me, I went shopping."

What's correct?

Comment: *My friend and I* is correct, as you and your friend are still the subject of the sentence (albeit in apposition).  However, it is common to say *me and my friend,* particularly in colloquial situations.  If you are speaking in a formal register, use *my friend and I;* if not, use whichever you prefer.

Comment: @user61979 No, that is incorrect: one says “Me, I went shopping” in English, never “I, I went shopping.”

Comment: The preposed noun phrase is not the subject; it's an extra feature provided by the syntactic rule of [Left-Dislocation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/167283/15299).

Answer (score 3):

Given that these are acceptable:

- *Me*, I went shopping.
- *Us*, we went shopping.
- *Her*, she went shopping.
- *Him*, he went shopping.
- *Him **and** her*, they went shopping.
- *Them*, they went shopping.

Then that means you continue to use object-case pronouns in emphatic position, no matter how many of them you happen to find there:

- *My sister **and** me*, we went shopping.
- *Him **and** her **and** me*, we all went shopping together.

---

**The Moral of the Story:** Joining two object-case pronouns with a coördinating conjunction doth never a subject-case pronoun make.

Comment: I think that your answer is correct, but I'd consider a small rephrasing to make it clearer which side of the fence you're coming down on. "If A then B" could argue that A is right so B is too, or that B is ridiculous so A must be wrong.

Comment: Can these versions be considered short forms of 'Speaking of (As for) him, us, her...'? If so, is it possible to use 'myself' - as in 'speaking of myself'?

Answer (score 0):

My friend and I went shopping.  Rule of thumb is to eliminate "My" or "I" and read the sentence.

I went shopping.  My friend went shopping.  You always prefer another before yourself.

Comment: Hello Ms MJC, while what you have said has some validity, many many people on this site describe how people talk, not prescribe. You may wish to have a look at some of the questions to the right under RELATED to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score -1):

Me as putting myself first in a sentence is correct.  Example Me and my friend went shopping however if you were to put yourself second Example My friend and Me would be incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer has already been posted by Anonym in the first comment and doesn't provide any additional information. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.