# Is it natural to say "Me, I xyz"?

Tags: speech, conversation

I tend to put "me" in front of sentences when I'm trying to set them apart from a previously said opinion or view.

Examples:

> Me, I like pizza.

> Me, I'm cold.

Is it okay to say it like that in a conversation? It was pointed out to me that it's weird and now I'm not sure if I took that from another language (it seems fine to do this in French...).

Edit: I think I could replace it with "As for me, ..."

Comment: This is a natural syntactic rule in English called "Left Dislocation". It can also occur with the object -- _Him, I can't stand him_. And there is a "[Right Dislocation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/167283/15299)" to match: _He really likes pizza, him_.

Comment: They do this a lot more in French than in English (and in fact, it's sometimes grammatically required in French), but we definitely do it in informal English, too. Is it natural? How often do you do it? I think most native English speakers only do it occasionally.

Comment: You can view it as: "Me? I'm cold."

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard a native English speaker say this unless answering a question ("Who wants lunch?" "Me, I want lunch!"). I think it's fine to do what you do in Spanish too. Using "as for me,..." would work well, but it's unusual and formal (at least in my dialect). In informal speech, I would probably omit the "as" and just say, "For me,...".

Comment: That way of speaking is common in a number of UK regional dialects, also 'me' at the end of declarations about oneself - e.g. I'm tired, me.

Comment: I notice the BBC weather presenters like to say "It will be heavy, the rain."

Comment: They have to say that a lot at this time of year.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've never noticed any of them do that. Maybe I'll have to listen more carefully.

Comment: Brit Simon Whistler (host of numerous YouTube channels) does this almost constantly. It’s particularly jarring because it’s *not* in the script for the captions.

Answer (score -1):

This sort of reply is acceptable in the locution "me too" (Me too, I'm cold.) but otherwise it does not appear to be idiomatic. This is not found in print ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Me+I+am%2CMe+I%27m&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cme%20I%20am%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CMe%20I%20%27m%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bme%20I%20%27m%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMe%20I%20%27m%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cme%20I%20am%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CMe%20I%20%27m%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bme%20I%20%27m%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMe%20I%20%27m%3B%2Cc0)). "Me I am" yields just one result, the title of a book and this is probably not the expected syntax, a subject/verb inversion being necessary to understand the meaning (I am me).

Replacing "me" by "as for me" in this context will not do. "As for me" is fine in writing after an enumeration that can consist of just one element.

There are various ways to formulate this type of opposition.

1/ • Personally, I like pizza.

2/  • What's making me unconfortable is the cold.  (*possibly stressed "me"*)
      • What I can hardly bear is the cold. (*possibly stressed "I"*)
      • Being *cold* is *my* problem. (*stressed "cold"*)
       • The *cold* is my problem. (*stressed "cold"*)

Comment: The reference to *me too* may be misleading, because, in so far as such locutions can be heard, they seem to imply contrast, rather  than conformity, with others.

Comment: How many times must one say it? Ngrams are for written English, not necessarily spoken English.