# Is there a name for the UK English repeating of a subject in a sentence - IE "I can do science, me"

Tags: british-english

The catchphrase of an old British science show called Brainiac is "I can do science, me." I've noted the likes of Karl Pilkington in the UK doing this sort of "double subject" structure. "I'm a nice guy I am", "He's a good guy him", etc...

I cannot provide any more particular examples but I have seen this enough to associate it with British English, perhaps northern in particular. I've searched to find what this might be called but can't find any other discussions of it. Any insight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["We went swimming later in the afternoon, Jack and I."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167255/we-went-swimming-later-in-the-afternoon-jack-and-i)

Comment: @Laurel it does seem to - specifically the examples of: "He hates the Dodgers a lot, my Uncle Will. (Right-Dislocation of Subject NP)
My Uncle Will hates them a lot, the Dodgers. (" of Object NP)" seem to be what I'm looking for. As for why this happens in UK English, I am still uncertain - but at least I have a name to attribute to it now. Thank you for finding that for me.