# "Nice pub this" – what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw a video where this British person says "Nice pub this" and I'm wondering if that's actually a shorter way of saying "[A] nice pub this [is]."

Is this construction common in everyday British English? Does this form exist in American English at all?

Comment: It's an expression I've been familiar with for many years. 'Nice pub, this' / 'Nice shirt, that' / 'Nice day, today'. **Conversational deletion** is in play, perhaps from 'It's a nice pub, this is' (hence the usual comma), though 'This is a nice pub' is the more usual expanded form. I'd say it's more common in the north of England, and perhaps becoming generally less commonly heard. I can't find data on Google Ngrams.

Comment: Without any evidence to back me up, I'd say the construction is more common in British English but not out of the ordinary in American English.

Comment: [Right dislocation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/167283/15299) from _This is a nice pub_, followed by [conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299) of _it's_.

Comment: "A fine romance with no kisses / **A fine romance, my friend, this is**" (Jerome Kern with lyrics by Dorothy Fields)

Answer (score 0):

Odd question, this.
I suppose to non-native Englishspeakers this may seem a bit "Yodish" (https://grammarpartyblog.com/2011/05/04/speaking-yodish/)...

But native speakers do tend to express themselves in similarly flexible ways.